# How can I escape all unicode characters in a QString so that only ASCII is used and the result is as short as possible?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, escaping, non-ascii-characters, qstring

I'm searching for a safe method to escape all non-ASCII characters in a `QString` (and of course to un-escape them later) that will result in pure (printable) ASCII but yield the shortest possible string.

What I currently do is:

```
QByteArray excludes = QStringLiteral(" !\"#$&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]_{|}~").toUtf8();
auto escaped = QString::fromUtf8(someString.toUtf8().toPercentEncoding(excludes));
auto unEscaped = QString::fromUtf8(QByteArray::fromPercentEncoding(escaped.toUtf8()));
```

This is reliable and works perfectly in both directions. But the problem is that the result is quite long. An escaped character takes at least 6 chars:

E.g. `ê` is encoded as `%C3%AA`, or  would become `%F0%9F%98%8A`.

I tried to find a way to make this shorter. E.g. the shortest Base64 representation of `C3AA` would be `w6o`, for `F09F988A` it would be `8J+Yig`. Half the length of the percent encoded version. But I don't know how long the escaped sequence would be, so I would need to add a start and finish character like `&w6o;` or such – and then, only one single char would be cheaped out.

So: Is there a better (meaning shorter) way than the said percent encoding to reliably escape and unescape all non-ASCII characters in a `QString` (using C++ obviously ;-)?

Comment: You say "only ASCII" (128 characters), but then you talk about percent-encoding (9 characters) and base64 (64 characters). Do you want ASCII, printable ASCII, or something else? Assuming the printable ASCII, base64 is really good. Not optimal since there are more than 64 printable characters, but it's a fair compromise to make it faster and simpler. base64 encodes 3 bytes into 4 printable ASCII characters.

Comment: So the question is what do you encode using base64? That'll depend on the frequency of the characters. For example, if it's primarily ASCII, UTF-8+base64 is a good choice. If the characters are spread across the BMP, then maybe UTF-16+base64. etc

Comment: Please [edit] to add a tag to identify the language you are using. Is this [tag:c++]?

Comment: Yes, of course … I's about QByteArrays and QStrings, so it's Qt, and this is C++